# jquery clear ajax and hide div object

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Not sure what is going on. I am trying to upload users files via AJAX from `index.html` file which in-terms runs the POST to `upload.php` which then returns file short url code to the user.

In my case once a user uploads the file it gives the link and then if he goes and uploads another file without full page-refresh via F5 the script will re-upload previous file and the new file creating yet another short-code for previous file and a new-short code for the new file

Not to mention for some reason the actual div with the link that's being returned to user does not disapear once the new file is uploaded, so user gets code for old file and code for new file which I don't exactly want.

Once a file is uploaded its done and the POST should no longer have it and once user uploads a new file the div should only have short-code to the new file but not having 2 div's with 2 different codes to old a new files.

Here is the jQuery Code

```
(function () {
    var input = document.getElementById("images"), 
        formdata = false;

    function showUploadedItem (source) {
        var list = document.getElementById("image-list"),
            li   = document.createElement("li"),
            img  = document.createElement("img");
            a    = document.createElement("a");
        img.src = source;
        li.appendChild(img);
        list.appendChild(li);
        a.href = source;
    }   

    if (window.FormData) {
        formdata = new FormData();
        document.getElementById("btn").style.display = "none";
    }

    input.addEventListener("change", function (evt) {
        document.getElementById("response").innerHTML = "<div class='uploading'></div>"
        var i = 0, len = this.files.length, img, reader, file;

        for ( ; i < len; i++ ) {
            file = this.files[i];

            if (!!file.type.match(/image.*/)) {
                if ( window.FileReader ) {
                    reader = new FileReader();
                    reader.onloadend = function (e) { 
                        showUploadedItem(e.target.result, file.fileName);
                    };
                    reader.readAsDataURL(file);
                }
                if (formdata) {
                    formdata.append("images[]", file);
                }
            }   
        }

        if (formdata) {
            $.ajax({
                url: "upload.php",
                type: "POST",
                data: formdata,
                processData: false,
                contentType: false,
                success: function (res) {
                    document.getElementById("response").innerHTML = res;                    
                }
            });
        }
    }, false);
}());
```

And you can test the site at: [cyogen.com](http://cyogen.com) try to upload one file and then another after you get short link you will then understand what I mean.

Comment: Are the files actually uploading to the server? Because Ajax can't directly handle file uploads, you would have to be using an iframe or something similar to do it without a page refresh.

Comment: The files are being pushed to upload.php via POST method and from there own upload.php deals with moving the file that's being submitted via AJAX form.

Comment: Why using `document.getElementById` stuff in a jQuery environment btw?

Comment: @moonwave99 this is fairly old code that still uses jQuery 1.6.2 and I never rewritten it for some reason

Comment: @danL  actually using fileReader and formdata API's can upload with AJAX in browsers that support these API's ( not in IE<10)

Answer (score 1):

I visited the url that you had in your question, I noticed the `input` in your form is actually enabling the `multiple` option which [allows multiple files to be uploaded](http://www.w3schools.com/html5/att_input_multiple.asp), I think you need to remove this option if you want only one file to be uploaded each time.

Comment: Alright the line multiple was removed. However try uploading one image and then uploading the next one, what happens is that you will get 2 links to the same file to the very first file to be exact which is re-uploaded. And more files you add more new links you will get as older files that you uploaded are being re-uploaded again and again which should not happen